# MySQL cast the result of aggregation function to int

Tags: mysql

I have two columns which are have different types. The column client_bill has a type smallint(5) unsigned and the column bonus_part has a type float(6,2). I have a query

```
`SELECT IFNULL(SUM(client_bill + bonus_part), 0) AS bill
 FROM orders
 WHERE id_client = ? AND status = ? AND OrderedDate >= ?`
```

I need to cast the result of query to integer type

Comment: *I need to cast the result of query to integer type* Cast (or round) if you need...  What is the problem? what is your question?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. That is my question

Comment: FLOAT is wrong datatype for money column - alter it to DECIMAL.

Comment: You are right but this is a legacy and there is a big problem to do alter because the database is huge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast to unsigned:

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(client_bill + CAST(bonus_part AS UNSIGNED)), 0) AS bill
FROM orders
WHERE id_client = ? AND status = ? AND OrderedDate >= ?;
```

Note that we only would need to cast the `bonus_part` to an integer as the `client_bill`, as well as the default sum value, are already integers.